# How to move circle with lefteyetransform ARKit2

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm trying to develop a game that moves the circle according the left eye

```
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let  screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        let    camera = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera
        let pippo = simd_mul((anchor.transform),faceAnchor.leftEyeTransform)
        var j: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(pippo.columns.3.x ,pippo.columns.3.y , -pippo.columns.3.z);
        self.circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(   j.x * Float(screenHeight/2) ),y:CGFloat(  j.y * Float(screenWidth/2) )), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
        self.shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.shapeLayer.path = self.circlePath.cgPath
        self.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.shapeLayer)
```

I move a bit the circle, but it is centered on the leftmost part of the screen (instead of being in the middle) and the movement  doesn't cover the whole screen, but just  a part of it, how can I solve it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more code and a picture? Not very clear what is going on, why are you using CAShapeLayer instead of SKShapeNode for instance, and why you recreate it instead of just moving.